# Exception: Service invoked too many times for one day: gmail

Tags: google-apps-script, google-cloud-platform, gmail

We have a very simple Google Script that deletes any emails older than 90 days for a GSuite email account. It is set to run every hour due to the undocumented 500 result limit on [gmailApp.Search](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-app#search(String)) and needing to delete thousands of emails (roughly 7500/day):

```
function deleteOldEmail() {
    var threads = GmailApp.search('in:inbox older_than:90d'); 

    Logger.log('Found: ' + threads.length + ' Emails');

    var batchSize = 100
    for (j = 0; j < threads.length; j+=batchSize) {
        GmailApp.moveThreadsToTrash(threads.slice(j, j+batchSize));
    }

    Logger.log('Deleted: ' + j + ' Emails');
}
```

Under "My Executions" shows that this is constantly failing with the message:

> Exception: Service invoked too many times for one day: gmail. at deleteOldEmail(Code:4:26)

Going to the Google Cloud Platform (GCP) dashboard by selecting Resources->Cloud Platform Project and clicking the name of the project shows the error on the Error Reporting card, and there are API requests on the APIs card. When clicking "Go to APIs Overview" the resulting page is showing no information at all:

[image]

I need to determine which quota is being hit, and how. Clicking on the Apps Script API from the above page shows no traffic and no data under quotas. Clicking on the Gmail API from the above page shows no traffic and no data under quotas. Under IAM & Admin->Quotas there is 0 usage for all APIs listed.

How does one determine what quota is being hit?

**EDIT:** I turned on email notices for failures on the trigger. It said it was Line #12, which is the GmailApp.moveThreadsToTrash() method. Its not the search that was the issue as some other posts have questioned (without answer).

The script is now running again as of noon today, so I will be able to count the number of times it runs multiplied by 500 and get a rough idea. I will post an update when it happens as there are a lot of posts that I have found regarding this with no solution.

**EDIT 2:** Well, unfortunately I have yet to hit the limit again. The script has deleted just shy of 11K in 24 hours at its peak.

Answer (score 0):

### Google has two types of Quotas:

1. The API specific quotas that you can see in your GCP
2. In addition, there are Apps Script quotas that apply also if you do not use any APIs.

`Service invoked too many times for one day` is an exception message that you get if you hit Apps Script quotas, which you can consult [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas).

As you see, for the usage of Apps Script methods there are maximum daily quotas which you can hit independently of the usage of APIs and that depend on your account type.

In your case, it is `GmailApp` (not Gmail API!) that makes you hit the quotas.

There is no specific mentioning of `GmailApp.search` and `GmailApp.moveThreadsToTrash` requests, but assuming that they count towards 
`Email read/write` requests, they should be limited to 20,000 per day for a Consumer (free) user account.

Comment: Yeah, I have seen the quotas page. Like you said, it doesnt really explain which quota the search or moveThreadsToTrash methods apply to. If it is the "email read/write" quota, we are not even coming close to the 20K limit. As noted in the OP its a G Suite account, so the limit should actually be 50K / day.

Comment: If you have a G Suite account, I recommend you to contact GSuite support for more detailed information on the Quota you are using!